# Google Pub/Sub API gets OAUTH2 authentication failure when trying to connect to a specific endpoint

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, google-cloud-pubsub

Recently I have been trying to add ordering-key support to my Google Pub/Sub services.  The [Google Pub/Sub ordering-key documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#using-ordering-keys) indicates that when using multiple publishers, you should connect to a particular Google endpoint to ensure that the ordering works correctly.  Ok fine.

However, when I add the `settings.setEndpoint(...)` calls to the following code, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See ...

If I comment out the endpoint calls and connect to the global endpoints then the code works so I don't think there is a problem with the service account key.  As far as I can tell there isn't a way to specify an endpoint when creating a service account key.

Here is my code.  We are using the `com.google.cloud.google-cloud-pubsub-1.114.3.jar` API jar although I get the same error when I try `1.120.22` which looks to be the latest.

```java
final String PROJECT_ID = "...";
final String TOPIC_NAME = "test-20221025-153636-7318";
final String ENDPOINT = "us-east1-pubsub.googleapis.com:443";
final String CREDENTIALS = "{\n" //
        + "  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n" //
        + "  \"project_id\": \"" + PROJECT_ID + "\",\n" //
        + "  \"private_key_id\": \"...\",\n" //
        + "  \"private_key\": ...\"" //
        + "  \"client_email\": \"...\",\n" //
        + "  \"client_id\": \"...\",\n" //
        + ...
        + "}\n";

TopicName googleTopicName = ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT_ID, TOPIC_NAME);
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider
        .create(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(CREDENTIALS.getBytes())));
// create the publisher
Publisher.Builder publisherBuilder = Publisher.newBuilder(googleTopicName);
publisherBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
// if I comment this out then the code works fine
publisherBuilder.setEndpoint(ENDPOINT);
publisherBuilder.setEnableMessageOrdering(true);
Publisher publisher = publisherBuilder.build();
// publish a message
PubsubMessage message = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setMessageId("id")
        .setData(ByteString.copyFrom("data", Charset.defaultCharset()))
        .setOrderingKey("foo").build();
ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(message);
System.out.println("Publishing message returned: " + future.get());
```

Any idea what is going on?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I replicated this (Although in python, I used the same endpoint) and I successfully came up with the output with no error. Assuming you are using java client library have you tried following the steps here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library Specially at authentication part

Comment: Thanks for that @NestorCenizaJr.  This is an automated test that runs without human interaction so I was hoping that the key that I'm using does not need any additional authentication.  At least it doesn't when connecting to the global endpoint.

Comment: Hey @NestorCenizaJr.  I found the problem (see below).  I'm curious why the python API library doesn't need scoped credentials.  Can you confirm that you didn't have to do anything special with your credentials when working in python?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I add the settings.setEndpoint(...) calls to the following code, I am getting the following exception: ... UnauthenticatedException ...

After more research, I found this [github issue thread](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/issues/930) on the Pub/Sub Github page that matches my problem precisely.  Guess I should have started there but hopefully this question/answer will help others.

The problem seems to be that the service account credentials do not have the right scopes.  I mean of course they don't.

Changing the credentials creation code to the following makes my little test program work now:

```
ServiceAccountCredentials sac = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(CREDENTIALS.getBytes()));
GoogleCredentials scopedCredentials =
    sac.createScoped(PublisherStubSettings.getDefaultServiceScopes());
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
    FixedCredentialsProvider.create(scopedCredentials);
```

I have yet to find any mention of this in the Google documentation unfortunately.  If anyone finds a mention please add a comment so I can reference it here.  The requirement of setting *default* scopes on the credentials to get it to work seems odd.

I'm also not sure if this is a generic issue.  If you are doing anything with the Google API endpoint, do you need to get the default scopes on your credentials?  If I have some time I will do some more tests on this.  Add a comment if you know the answer.

Hope this helps others.